# Regular expression to match pattern with (optional) the same pattern inside

Tags: regex, nested

So i have to find all calls of functions in code like: _t(anything) Also there can be parameters given to those calls like: "_t(anything, _t(anything2))" and for such examples i want to match only top call of _t() is there any way to do this ?

Comment: What language? It is easily possible(if I understand the question correctly) but some languages might not have this function of regex implemented.

Comment: Ill be loking for such strings in js files using PHP to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Programming is about picking the right tool for the job, and regular expressions is not really the right tool for matching only the top-level portion of a function. However, it is a rather simple task to write a program to grab the top level portion, here's a program, written in C++, that will accomplish this. It will parse the string stored in the variable "str", and find the top level portions of the function stored in "func", so in this case it finds "_t("

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    string str = "_t(another, anything)\nanything0 _t(anything, _t(anything2))\n_t(anything)\n_m(this, should, not, match)\n_t(anything1, anything2)";
    string func = "_t(";

    int pos = 0;
    int lastPos = 0;

    while (pos != -1) {
      pos = str.find (func, lastPos);

      if (pos == -1) break;

      int depth = 1;
      string tmp;

      pos += func.size ();
      while (depth > 0) {
        if (str[pos] == '(') {
          depth++;
        }
        else if (str[pos] == ')') {
          depth--;
        }

        if (depth != 0) {
          tmp += str[pos];
        }
        pos++;
      }

      cout << tmp << endl;

      lastPos = pos;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Given the following input (stored in the string "str"):

```
_t(another, anything)
anything0 _t(anything, _t(anything2))
_t(anything)
_m(this, should, not, match)
_t(anything1, anything2)
```

The following is the output:

```
another, anything
anything, _t(anything2)
anything
anything1, anything2
```

---

**Update:**
I do feel that, when dealing with nested items, regex isn't really the best solution, however, this might work for what you need:

```
_t\(([\w\d _\(\),]+)?\)
```

Here's an example, in PHP (as you said you were using in another comment):

```php
<?php 
$pattern = '/_t\(([\w\d _\(\),]+)?\)/';
$subject = '_t(another, anything)\nanything0 _t(anything, _t(anything2))\n_t(anything)\n_m(this, should, not, match)\n_t(anything1, anything2)';

preg_match_all ($pattern, $subject, $matches);

print_r ($matches);
?>
```

The output from this is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => _t(another, anything)
            [1] => _t(anything, _t(anything2))
            [2] => _t(anything)
            [3] => _t(anything1, anything2)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => another, anything
            [1] => anything, _t(anything2)
            [2] => anything
            [3] => anything1, anything2
        )

)
```

And that seems to match what you're looking for, in the $matches[1] array.

Comment: I was thinking about such solution but i thought there is an easier way to do it using regexp as "they can find anything u want" :D thx for giving an idea, if there is really no way to do it using regexp ill do it like that.

Comment: I was playing around with some regex for this, and if you wanted to just use regex, this might work for what you need: `_t\(([\w\d _\(\),]+)?\)`. See updated post for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to match the function names only or remove parameters (including non-top-level calls). Anyways [here](http://regexr.com?3215f) is a replace regex which outputs:

```
_t()
_t()
_t()
```

with

```
_t(anything, _t(anything2))
_t(anything)
_t(anything1, anything2)
```

as input:

```
/(_t\().*(\))/\1\2/g
```

Comment: I dont want to replace anything, just want to find all occurences of _t() with any parameter given, also _t call itself.

Your solution doesnt work for foo(_t())

Comment: Well after your clarification, I must say `Regular Expressions` are not the right tool for dealing with nested and recursive structures. That's because state machines can't store/recall data (parentheses depth in this case) when moving from one state to another. So `Regular Expressions` are not suitable for your job :)